# Flex 4.5 - Transparent Background on Spark DataGrid Headers

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, header, transparent, flex-spark

In short, I am attempting to get this result:

[image: Spark DataGrid]

I almost got it, but the part that's giving me trouble is making the header background transparent. I am making a custom MXML skin based on the default Spark DataGrid skin. I tried setting the `contentBackgroundAlpha` to 0 on the columnHeaderGroup and the headerRenderer, but that didn't work. I tried setting `visible` to false for either of those, but that made it so that the text didn't show up either, so that didn't work. There is no setting for `backgroundAlpha` in either of those two, so I'm not sure what else to try.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy everything from default header renderer... then remove everything that says "s:Rect", then set that as your header renderer for each column. Here's the code you should end up with as your header renderer: http://pastebin.com/XPu1cSK9

You don't even need to make a skin for the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at the mx.skins.spark.DataGridHeaderBackgroundSkin

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
minWidth="21" minHeight="19">

<fx:Script>
    /**
     * @private
     */
    override protected function initializationComplete():void
    {
        useChromeColor = true;
        super.initializationComplete();
    }
</fx:Script>

<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" alpha="0">
</s:Rect>

<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" alpha="0">
</s:Rect>

<s:Rect left="0" right="0" bottom="0" height="9" alpha="0">
</s:Rect>

<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" height="9" alpha="0">
</s:Rect>

<s:Rect left="0" right="0" bottom="0" height="1" alpha="0">
</s:Rect>

</s:SparkSkin>
```

Comment: What do I apply that skin to? The Spark DataGrid doesn't have a `headerSkinClass` or `headerStyleName` property.